# How to bind common Info-mode navigation to single keys in spacemacs?

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, info

I wish that more keys were bound in Info mode in spacemacs.  For example:

- `Info-next` doesn't seem to be bound (`n` instead is `evil-ex-search-next`, which I never use)
- Following a reference requires two key presses: `m <RET>` (`RET` is bound to `evil-ret`, which doesn't seem useful in Info)

However:

- `SPC h SPC Info` doesn't seem to turn up where the key bindings live (to find configuration I can base my key bindings on)
- I'm not sure the best way to bind a single character in Info mode to follow a reference or to go to the next node

How can I bind next node and follow reference to single keys (and how to discover this kind of thing better the next time)?